# Boost::spirit illegal_backtracking exception

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

I use Boost.Spirit.Lex and .Qi for a simple calculator project and (as usual) it gives me some pain to debug and use. The debug prints:

```
<expression>
  <try>boost::spirit::multi_pass::illegal_backtracking
```

This exception is thrown and I can't understand why. I use macros in my code and it would be a pain to give a minimal example so I give the [whole project](http://www.hyc.io/sash.zip). Just do "make" at the root, and then launch ./sash, a prompt will appear, if you want to test just do "-echo $5-8".

It seems that Google didn't find any similar problems about this exception...

The parser is in arithmetic/, and the call of the parser is at the end of arithmetic/evaluator.cpp

Any helps greatly appreciate.

Comment: `./sash <<<"-echo $5*8"` prints "No matches". `./sash <<<"echo $5*8"` prints "*8". What exactly did you want tried?

Comment: I don't know why "<<<" doesn't work, however if you launch ./sash and then type "-echo $8-7" it will "work". Please don't use * or \ (or escape them with \), I update my example, sorry about that.

Comment: Of course, `<<<` does work. I see you changed the sample so it doesn't trigger the _wildcard_ expansion code any more :) See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is breaking because BOOST_SPIRIT_QI_DEBUG as well as the `on_error<>` handler seem to use iterators after they might have been invalidated.

To be honest, I'm not completely sure how this could happen.

### Background

AFAICT lexertl uses `spirit::multipass<>` with a `split_functor` input policy and a `split_std_deque` storage policy <sup>[1]</sup>.

Now, (luckily?) the checking policy is `buf_id_check` which means that the iterator will check for invalidation at the time of dereference.

Iterators are expected to be invalidated if

1. the iterator is derefenced, growing the buffer to >16 tokens ***and*** the iterator is the only one referring to the shared state.
2. or somewhere along the line `clear_queue` is called explicitely (e.g. from the `flush_multi_path` primitive in the Spirit Repository)

Honestly I don't see any of these two conditions being met. A quick and dirty

```
token_iterator_type clone = iter; // just to make it non-unique...
```

in `evaluator.cpp` doesn't make a difference (ruling out reason #1)

Temporary disabling the `docheck` implementation in the `buf_id_check_policy` made valgrind point out that `on_error<>` and BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG* are causing invalid memory references. Commenting *both* indeed makes all problems go away (and the `eval_expression` now works).

However, this is likely not your preferred solution.

## Proposed solution

Since

- you're working on a fixed, in-memory container representing the input you don't really need `multi_pass` behaviour emulation
- you're using a trivial grammar, you don't really benefit from *lexertl* - while you are getting a lot of added complexity (as you can see)

I've quickly refactored some code: https://github.com/sehe/sash-refactor/commits/master

- commit dec31496 *`sanity - lets do without macros`*
   4 files changed, 59 insertions(+), 146 deletions(-)
- commit 6056574c *`dead code, excess scope, excess instantiation`*
   5 files changed, 38 insertions(+), 62 deletions(-)
- commit 99d441db *`remove lexer`*
   9 files changed, 25 insertions(+), 177 deletions(-)

Now, you will find that your code is generally much simpler, also much shorter, not running into multi_pass limits and you can still have SPIRIT_DEBUG as well as `on_error` handling :) In the end

- binary size in -g3 is ***reduced from 16Mb to 6.5Mb***
- a **net 263 lines of code** have been removed
- more importantly, **it works**

Here's some samples (without debug output):

```
$ ./sash <<< '-echo $8-9'
    -1
    Warning: Empty environment variable "8-9".
$ ./sash <<< '-echo $8\*9'
    72
    Warning: Empty environment variable "8*9".
$ ./sash <<< '-echo $8\*(9-1)'
    64
    Warning: Empty environment variable "8*(9-1)".
$ ./sash <<< '-echo $--+-+8\*(9-1)'
    -64
    Warning: Empty environment variable "--+-+8*(9-1)".
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Which, despite it's name, buffers previously seen tokens in a `std::vector<>`

Comment: Posting a small selfcontained demo of the resulting expression evaluator for the benefit of future SO visitors: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50a36ac8b5613f2e (202 LoC)

Comment: sehe, you are one crazy spirit `;-)`

Comment: Many thanks, I should have think to remove the lexer, I used an old project that I naively adapted for this one. Beyond that, thanks for the code clarification, using these macros was not a good idea for such a little project.